# How to make tree mapping tail-recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, tree, tail-recursion

Suppose I have a tree data structure like this:

```
trait Node { val name: String }
case class BranchNode(name: String, children: List[Node]) extends Node
case class LeafNode(name: String) extends Node
```

Suppose also I've got a function to map over leaves:

```
def mapLeaves(root: Node, f: LeafNode => LeafNode): Node = root match {
  case ln: LeafNode => f(ln)
  case bn: BranchNode => BranchNode(bn.name, bn.children.map(ch => mapLeaves(ch, f)))
}
```

Now I am trying to make this function *tail-recursive* but having a hard time to figure out how to do it. I've read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38930760/tail-recursive-functions-for-binarytree) but still don't know to make that binary tree solution work for a multiway tree.

How would you rewrite `mapLeaves` to make it tail-recursive?

Comment: I think you need some intermediate format, as you see in your mentioned 'answer' -  there is a List (which is also the result as a difference to your problem)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I concur I need some "todo list" (as in the mentioned answer) but I cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Can you use [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/) or scalaz?

Comment: I would prefer not to (in this particular case).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Call stack" and "recursion" are merely popular design patterns that later got incorporated into most programming languages (and thus became mostly "invisible"). There is nothing that prevents you from reimplementing both with heap data structures. So, here is "the obvious" 1960's TAOCP retro-style solution:

```
trait Node { val name: String }
case class BranchNode(name: String, children: List[Node]) extends Node
case class LeafNode(name: String) extends Node

def mapLeaves(root: Node, f: LeafNode => LeafNode): Node = {
  case class Frame(name: String, mapped: List[Node], todos: List[Node])
  @annotation.tailrec
  def step(stack: List[Frame]): Node = stack match {
    // "return / pop a stack-frame"
    case Frame(name, done, Nil) :: tail => {
      val ret = BranchNode(name, done.reverse)
      tail match {
        case Nil => ret
        case Frame(tn, td, tt) :: more => {
          step(Frame(tn, ret :: td, tt) :: more)
        }
      }
    }
    case Frame(name, done, x :: xs) :: tail => x match {
      // "recursion base"
      case l @ LeafNode(_) => step(Frame(name, f(l) :: done, xs) :: tail)
      // "recursive call"
      case BranchNode(n, cs) => step(Frame(n, Nil, cs) :: Frame(name, done, xs) :: tail)
    }
    case Nil => throw new Error("shouldn't happen")
  }
  root match {
    case l @ LeafNode(_) => f(l)
    case b @ BranchNode(n, cs) => step(List(Frame(n, Nil, cs)))
  }
}
```

The tail-recursive `step` function takes a reified stack with "stack frames". A "stack frame" stores the name of the branch node that is currently being processed, a list of child nodes that have already been processed, and the list of the remaining nodes that still must be processed later. This roughly corresponds to an actual stack frame of your recursive `mapLeaves` function.

With this data structure,

- returning from recursive calls corresponds to deconstructing a `Frame` object, and either returning the final result, or at least making the `stack` one frame shorter.
- recursive calls correspond to a step that prepends a `Frame` to the `stack`
- base case (invoking `f` on leaves) does not create or remove any frames

Once one understands how the usually invisible stack frames are represented explicitly, the translation is straightforward and mostly mechanical.

Example:

```
val example = BranchNode("x", List(
  BranchNode("y", List(
    LeafNode("a"),
    LeafNode("b")
  )),
  BranchNode("z", List(
    LeafNode("c"),
    BranchNode("v", List(
      LeafNode("d"),
      LeafNode("e")
    ))
  ))
))

println(mapLeaves(example, { case LeafNode(n) => LeafNode(n.toUpperCase) }))
```

Output (indented):

```
BranchNode(x,List(
  BranchNode(y,List(
    LeafNode(A),
    LeafNode(B)
  )),
  BranchNode(z, List(
    LeafNode(C),
    BranchNode(v,List(
      LeafNode(D),
      LeafNode(E)
    ))
  ))
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for so detailed answer. I understand how to implement call stack explicitly. Now I am just wondering how to simplify this solution.

Answer (score 8):

It might be easier to implement it using a technique called [trampoline](https://medium.com/@olxc/trampolining-and-stack-safety-in-scala-d8e86474ddfa).
If you use it, you'd be able to use two functions calling itself doing mutual recursion (with `tailrec`, you are limited to one function). Similarly to `tailrec` this recursion will be transformed to plain loop.

Trampolines are implemented in scala standard library in `scala.util.control.TailCalls`.

```
import scala.util.control.TailCalls.{TailRec, done, tailcall}

def mapLeaves(root: Node, f: LeafNode => LeafNode): Node = {

  //two inner functions doing mutual recursion

  //iterates recursively over children of node
  def iterate(nodes: List[Node]): TailRec[List[Node]] = {
     nodes match {
       case x :: xs => tailcall(deepMap(x)) //it calls with mutual recursion deepMap which maps over children of node 
         .flatMap(node => iterate(xs).map(node :: _)) //you can flat map over TailRec
       case Nil => done(Nil)
     }
  }

  //recursively visits all branches
  def deepMap(node: Node):  TailRec[Node] = {
    node match {
      case ln: LeafNode => done(f(ln))
      case bn: BranchNode => tailcall(iterate(bn.children))
         .map(BranchNode(bn.name, _)) //calls mutually iterate
    }
  }

  deepMap(root).result //unwrap result to plain node
}
```

Instead of `TailCalls` you could also use `Eval` from `Cats` or `Trampoline` from `scalaz`.

With that implementation function worked without problems:

```
def build(counter: Int): Node = {
  if (counter > 0) {
    BranchNode("branch", List(build(counter-1)))
  } else {
    LeafNode("leaf")
  }
}

val root = build(4000)

mapLeaves(root, x => x.copy(name = x.name.reverse)) // no problems
```

When I ran that example with your implementation it caused `java.lang.StackOverflowError` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for introducing trampolines. I need to learn about them.